# регулярное выражение поиска и преобразования <img src *** /> в тексте

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста, что то я где то ошибся,
рег выражение дублирует контент, т.е. я так полагаю, что оно не просто преобразует тег img с его содержимым, но и захватывает больше.

Нужно обрабатывать теги такого плана:

```
<img class="leftimg" 
src="https://example.ru/img/shema/2016-05-20%2013-58-37.jpg" 
alt="Забор из профнастила" width="550" height="309" />
```

Регулярное выражение

```
$content = preg_replace('!<img(.*?)src(.*?)alt="(.*?)" width(.*?)height(.*?)\s\/>!si',

'<span itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">

<span itemprop="name" style="display:none;">\\3</span>

<span itemprop="author" style="display:none;">Author</span>

<img itemprop="url contentUrl" \\1 src\\2 alt="\\3" title="\\3" width\\4 height\\5 />

<meta itemprop="width" content\\4>

<meta itemprop="height" content\\5></span>',$content);
```

Comment: Приводите [mcve]. У меня все работает https://regex101.com/r/G1JWup/1

Comment: И еще https://ideone.com/ftD39b

Comment: Я видимо неправильно поставил вопрос. Вернее сказать только что обнаружил вот что: при рокировке местами height и weight выражение не подходит, появляется третья картинка, хотя их всего две (( можно ли как то решить эту проблему?

Comment: Это свидетельство того, что нельзя парсить HTML с помощью регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 0):

@Dikkiy Вместо `width(.*?)height(.*?)` попробуйте так: `[width|height]="([^"]*)"`, или без квадратных скобок: `width|height`.

`"(.*?)"`, лучше заменить на `"([^"]*)"`, чтобы действовало в пределах кавычек.