# regexp как получить атрибуты img тега

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть изображения в тесте, нужно получить атрибуты тега img с последующим изменением.
Атрибуты могут находиться в произвольном порядке. Цель - применение микроразметки Shema.org

```
<img src="https://chelzabor.ru/img/shema/3peremichki.jpg" 
alt="описание" width="300" height="200" caption="false">
```

Элемент Caption не важен, но он может быть, а может и не быть
width и height могут быть поменяны местами,
alt может быть как перед указанием размеров, так и после

Вот это работает, только если атрибуты расположены в том порядке, которые в регулярке, если попадаются изображения с атрибутами в другой раскладке, то контент "троит", абзацы размножаются ((

```
$content = preg_replace('!<img(.*?)src(.*?)alt="(.*?)" (width|height)=(.*?)
(width|height)=(.*?)(/>| />)!si',
'<span itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
<span itemprop="name" style="display:none;">\\3</span>
<span itemprop="author" style="display:none;">Author</span>
<img itemprop="url contentUrl" \\1 src\\2 alt="\\3" title="\\3" \\4=\\5 \\6=\\7 />
<meta itemprop="\\4" content=\\5>
<meta itemprop="\\6" content=\\7>
</span>'."\n\n",$content);

echo $content;
```

Comment: и действительно, почему бы не закручивать молотком шурупы.

Comment: Ну, так подскажите, где эта отвертка?

Comment: если вы разбираете html-документ или его часть, то и используйте инструменты позволяющие работать с его структурой, DOMDocument Или часто встречаемый тут simple_html_dom

Comment: Зачем плодить вопросы? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794048/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-img-src-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment1252223_794048

Comment: потому что та тема умерла, а вопрос срочный

Comment: @Dikkiy, в моём ответе была ошибка `(1 !== end)` исправлена на `(_string.length !== end)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

автор, ну коли срочный, с тебя "лайк,подписка,все дела"

хоть я и согласен с @teran вот решение, опа, а тега php нету!! нуу, в общем вот решение на js, предполагается что значение атрибутов в двойных ковычках

```js
void function (_str) {
 /**
  * исходная строка
 */
 let str = ''
 str = _str
 /**
  * массив строк
 */
 let arr = []
 /**
  * контейнер o[_i][key] = val
  * _i - номер строки arr
  * key - имя атрибута
  * val - значение
  */
 let o = {}
 // -->

 /**
  * заменить переход строки на пробел
  */
 str = str.replace(/\n/g, ' ')
 /**
  * занести в массив
  */
 arr = str.match(/<[^>]+>/g)
 /**
  * убрать из массива arr закрывающие теги </*>
  */
 arr = arr.filter(_str => ('/' === _str[1]) ? false : true)
 /**
  * magi
 */
 arr.forEach(magi)
 // <--
 console.log(
  arr
 );
 console.log(
  o
 );
 // ---
 function magi(_string = '', _i = 0) {
  _string = foo(_string, _i)
  _string = _string.replace(/((\s)+(\s)*)/g, ' ')
  if ('/' === _string[_string.length - 2]) {
   _string = _string.substring(0, _string.length - 2)
  } else {
   _string = _string.substring(0, _string.length - 1)
  }
  let arr = _string.split(' ')
  for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
   if(''!=arr[i])o[_i][arr[i]] = true
  }
  return _string
 }
 function foo(_string = '', _i = 0) {
  let g = _string.indexOf('=')
  let start, end, key, param
  jjK:
  for (start = g - 1; start > 0;) {
   if ((' ' === _string[start]) || (' ' === _string[start])) {
    start++
    break jjK;
   }
   start--
  }
  if (1 !== start) {
   key = _string.substring(start, g)
  } else {
   throw new Error('никогда такого не должно быть 1')
  }
  jjP:
  for (end = g + 2; end < _string.length;) {
   if (('"' === _string[end]) && ('\\' !== _string[end - 1])) {
    end--
    break jjP;
   }
   end++
  }
  if (_string.length !== end) {
   param = _string.substring(g + 2, end + 1)
  } else {
   throw new Error('никогда такого не должно быть 2')
  }
  if (!o[_i]) o[_i] = {}
  o[_i][key] = param
  _string = _string.replace(_string.substring(start, end + 2), '')

  if (_string.indexOf('=') > -1) {
   _string = foo(_string, _i)
  }
  return _string;
 }
}(`
<span itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
шум шум
шум-шум шум
 <span itemprop="name" style="display:none;">qqqd</span>
 шум-шум шум
 <span itemprop="author" style="display:none;">Author</span>
 шум-шум шум
 <img class="leftimg"
 src="https://example.ru/img/shema/2016-05-20%2013-58-37.jpg"
 alt="Забор из профнастила" width="550" height="309" />
 шум-шум шум
 <img src="https://chelzabor.ru/img/shema/3peremichki.jpg"
 alt="описание" width="300" height="200" caption="false">
 шум-шум шум
 <meta itemprop="width">
 шум-шум шум
 <meta itemprop="height">
 </span>
 шум-шум шум
 `)
```